# Try convert WPF application using the bridge

Tags: desktop-bridge

When running DesktopAppConverter.exe getting the exception: Cannot set "Executable" because only strings can be used as values to set XmlNode properties. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: add more details please. How does your AppExecutable field look like?

Comment: I'm having the same issue too. My AppExecutable parameter is just the filename in double quotes (*"ColorCapture.exe"*). My package only contains two files, the executable and a help (CHM) file.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have 2 executables *with the exact same name* inside your package (but in different folders)?

That could cause this issue.